# Cant able to Upload Images From Gallery (Crashes or Out Of Memory Occurs)

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-gallery, android-image-capture

1. Opening The Gallery App

   ```
               Intent intent = new Intent();
               intent.setType("image/*");
               intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
               dialog1.dismiss();
               startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
   ```
2. After selecting Goes to OnActivityResult

   ```
           selectedImageUri = data.getData();
           selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);

           if(selectedImagePath==null)
           {
               Toast.makeText(MyProfileNewActivity.this, "Wrong File Please Select From Gallery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
           else
           {

               UploadProfilePicGallery uppg=new UploadProfilePicGallery();
               uppg.execute();
           }**
   ```
3. Starts The Asynctask to Upload the Image to the Server using AndroidMultiPartEntity

   ```
     public class UploadProfilePicGallery extends AsyncTask<Void,String,String>
       {

   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {

       //sourceFileUri.replace(sourceFileUri, "jagan");
       //

       int day, month, year;
       int second, minute, hour;
       GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar();

       day = date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
       month = date.get(Calendar.MONTH);
       year = date.get(Calendar.YEAR);

       second = date.get(Calendar.SECOND);
       minute = date.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
       hour = date.get(Calendar.HOUR);

       String name = (hour + "" + minute + "" + second + "" + day + "" + (month + 1) + "" + year);
       String tag = name + ".jpg";
       String fileName = selectedImagePath.replace(selectedImagePath, tag);

       HttpURLConnection conn = null;
       DataOutputStream dos = null;
       String lineEnd = "\r\n";
       String twoHyphens = "--";
       String boundary = "*****";
       int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
       byte[] buffer;
       int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

       File sourceFile = new File(selectedImagePath);
       try {
           Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(sourceFile.getAbsolutePath());
           ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
           byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();
           bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 10, bos);
           bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 10, bos);
           bmp = getResizedBitmap(bmp, 100);
           bitmapdata=bos.toByteArray();
           bProfileBitmap=bmp;
           FileOutputStream fos= null;
           try {
               fos = new FileOutputStream(sourceFile);
           } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

           try {
               fos.write(bitmapdata);
               fos.flush();
               fos.close();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
       catch(OutOfMemoryError o)
       {
           return "Out Of Memory Error";
       }



       if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

           // dialog.dismiss();

           Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :" + "");
           result="file missing";
           return result;

       } else {
           try {

               // open a URL connection to the Servlet
               File sourceFile1 = new File(selectedImagePath);
               FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile1);
               URL url = new URL(URLPath+"FileUploadGallery.php");

               // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
               conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
               conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
               conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
               conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
               conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
               conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
               conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
               conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
               conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); //===============
               session.setPicName(fileName);
               dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

               dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
               dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                       + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);


               // create a buffer of  maximum size
               bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

               bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
               buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

               // read file and write it into form...
               bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

               while (bytesRead > 0) {

                   dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                   bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                   bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                   bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

               }

               // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
               dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

               // Responses from the server (code and message)
               serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
               String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

               Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                       + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

               if (serverResponseCode == 200) {
                   result= "File Upload Completed";
               }

               //close the streams //
               fileInputStream.close();
               dos.flush();
               dos.close();

           } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
               ex.printStackTrace();
               result ="MalformedURLException";
               Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
               result = "Exception";
               Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);
           }
           return result;
       }
   }
   ```
4. Note The Error Comes Only When The User Selects the image which is taken by the camera... Other then that, downloaded images are able to Upload from Gallery. (Sometimes Crashes Sometimes OutOfMemoryErrorOccurs)

Please Give Me a solution i worked on this more then 3 days i cant able to find out the problem........
If You Had any other codes which is really working fine Please Share with me....

Answer (score 0):

Just try this by change your Intent.May it help

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
 startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
```